# Not able to run scala program even after compiling it

Tags: linux, scala

This is my scala code:

```
object world
{
    println("this is vaibhav")
}
```

i am able to compile it using scalac.

```
scalac object.scala
```

and these two files are generated:

```
world.class,world$.class
```

But when i run this:

```
scala world
```

it gives the follwing message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: world.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1670)
    at   scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:74)
    at         scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:56)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: You have no main method. So it can't find an entry point for your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of different ways with Scala.  One using body of object:

```
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello World: " + (args mkString ", "))
}
```

Note the `extends App` there. See [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App) about that.

The other using a `main` field of object:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Some [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/166) about that.

Answer (score 1):

As a Java program needs a `public static final main(String[] args) {}` method to be executed, a Scala one needs a `def main(args: Array[String]) {}` in your object.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that you will be using the Scala compiler (`scalac`) directly to build and manage any real Scala project. If you are starting with Scala I would suggest the following:

1. Use a build tool such as [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html) that will manage the dependecies and versions for you.
2. Use an IDE ([IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/scala.html)/[Eclipse](http://scala-ide.org/))